# C: Passing by reference during dynamic allocaion

Tags: c, initialization, pass-by-reference, allocation

My code is to allocate and initialize the array as follows (`floatalloc2` is a function used to allocate the 2D array):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alloc_arr(int adjwfd, int nx, int nz, float **G, float **L1, float **L2)
{
G = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
switch (adjwfd){
    case 1:
        L1 = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
        break;
    case 2:
        L2 = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
        break;
}
}

void init_arr(int adjwfd, int nx, int nz, float **G, float **L1, float **L2)
{
memset(G[0],0,nx*nz*sizeof(float));
switch (adjwfd){
    case 1:
        memset(L1[0],0,nx*nz*sizeof(float));
        break;
    case 2:
        memset(L2[0],0,nx*nz*sizeof(float));
        break;
}
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   

int adjwfd_P=1, nx=10, nz=10;
float **glob=NULL, **local1=NULL, **local2=NULL;

alloc_arr(adjwfd_P, nx, nz, glob, local1, local2);
init_arr(adjwfd_P, nx, nz, glob, local1, local2);

exit(0);
}
```

It passes the compilation. But when I run this code, it goes wrong says:

```
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
```

However, I found that if I change the `alloc_arr` as follows, it runs successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

void alloc_arr(int adjwfd, int nx, int nz, float ***G, float ***L1, float ***L2)
{
*G = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
switch (adjwfd){
    case 1:
        *L1 = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
        break;
    case 2:
        *L2 = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
        break;
}
}

void init_arr(int adjwfd, int nx, int nz, float **G, float **L1, float **L2)
{
memset(G[0],0,nx*nz*sizeof(float));
switch (adjwfd){
    case 1:
        memset(L1[0],0,nx*nz*sizeof(float));
        break;
    case 2:
        memset(L2[0],0,nx*nz*sizeof(float));
        break;
}
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   

int adjwfd_P=1, nx=10, nz=10;
float **glob=NULL, **local1=NULL, **local2=NULL;

alloc_arr(adjwfd_P, nx, nz, &glob, &local1, &local2);
init_arr(adjwfd_P, nx, nz, glob, local1, local2);

exit(0);
}
```

My question is why I have to take the address of the 2D array, and in the `alloc_arr` define 3D array only for the allocation part, whereas in other functions such as `init_arr`, I can just pass the original 2D array into the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why I have to take the address of the 2D array, and in the alloc_arr define 3D array only for the allocation part,......

In this case:

```
alloc_arr(adjwfd_P, nx, nz, glob, local1, local2);
```

You are actually passing the last three argument as `NULL` to `alloc_arr()` function parameter `G`, `L1` and `L2` as the `glob`, `local1` and `local2` are initialized with `NULL` and in `alloc_arr()`

```
void alloc_arr(int adjwfd, int nx, int nz, float **G, float **L1, float **L2)
{
G = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
.....
    L1 = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
.....
    L2 = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
.....
```

the memory is getting allocated to `G`, `L1` and `L2` which are **local variables** of `alloc_arr()` function. In the `main()`, the `glob`, `local1` and `local2` are **still null pointers** after `alloc_arr()` function returned. These null pointers passed to `init_arr()` and when trying to access them in `init_arr()` your program is giving segmentation fault.

and in this case

```
alloc_arr(adjwfd_P, nx, nz, &glob, &local1, &local2);
```

you are passing the address of pointers `glob`, `local1` and `local2` as argument to `alloc_arr()` function parameters `G`, `L1` and `L2`, which means `G`, `L1` and `L2` will hold address of `glob`, `local1` and `local2` pointers respectively.

```
void alloc_arr(int adjwfd, int nx, int nz, float ***G, float ***L1, float ***L2)
{
*G = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
.....
        *L1 = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
.....
        *L2 = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
.....
```

Dereferencing the pointer `G` will give `glob` pointer i.e. `*G` is `glob`. Similarly, dereferencing `*L1` and `*L2` will give pointer `local1` and `local2` respectively. So, when allocating memory to `*G`, `*L1` and `*L2` will actually allocate memory to `glob`, `local1` and `local2` pointers.

> whereas in other functions such as init_arr, I can just pass the original 2D array into the function?

Look at this:

```
alloc_arr(adjwfd_P, nx, nz, &glob, &local1, &local2);
init_arr(adjwfd_P, nx, nz, glob, local1, local2);
```

the `alloc_arr()` will allocate memory to `glob`, `local1` and `local2` which means after returning from `alloc_arr()` (assuming everything works as expected) the pointers `glob`, `local1` and `local2` are pointing to valid memory locations. In the `init_arr()` you are just passing those memory locations as argument to the `init_arr()` function parameters `G`, `L1` and `L2`. In the `init_arr()`, accessing `G`, `L1` and `L2` means it is accessing those memory locations.

---

Additional:

Follow good programming practice, make sure to free the allocated memory before program exits.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of [scopes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm).

In your `main` function you define:

```c
    // [...]
    float **array = NULL;
```

> Just a reminder that `array` is a pointer to a pointer (a 2D array as you call it).

In the `alloc_arr` function you want to change where `array` **in the main funcion** is pointing to. So you pass a reference to your local variable `array`. This way the `alloc_arr` function can change the local variable `array`.

A simpler example:

```c
void change_value(int *a)
{
    *a = 42;
}

void cant_change_value(int a)
{
    a = -21;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    // At this point a is 0
    cant_change_value(a);
    // a is still 0, because cant_change_value only modified the COPY of a
    // that was passed to the function
    change_value(&a);
    // a is now 42, because the function change_value received the address of a
    // and modified it's content
    return (0);
}
```

Back to your example, if the function `alloc_arr` didn't take a pointer to your 2D array it would not be able to modify your pointer in the `main` function.

[This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_passing_pointers_to_functions.htm) is a good introduction to how pointers work.

---

PS: Your variable names should be more explicit as to what they are. "`adjwfd_P`" might make sense to you, but it probably doesn't to anybody else reading your code.